# How to update a char column in MySQL by passing a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, char

I'm currently developing a simple php/mysql website as an assignment.

I need to update a char column in a table by passing a php variable. Issue is I don't know how to pass the variable as a string.

```
$verify = $_POST['verification'];

"UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code= . $verify . ";
```

Above query is not working for me. Running the query manually on mysql does work;

```
UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code="XYz12"
```

so I think the problem is passing the variable as a string. I tried a couple of different things but couldn't manage it...

Comment: Do check for errors when coding, it's your best friend ;) I know the answer (quotes), but you'll get some that'll pop up. Edit: Yep. Oh, and you're open to this => http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I am aware of the security issues but only recently started learning php. Just trying to get the functions working at the moment :)

Comment: You've got a few answers below that will/should solve the problem now, being the missing quotes, as I stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code='" . $verify . "'";
```

But of course this is very poor form. You need to ensure your variable has been properly escaped. I recommend using PDO prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code=?");
$stmt->execute(array($verify));
```

Answer (score 2):

the field verification_code is a string, this must be between simple quote like:

```
$query = "UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code='$verify'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct string for the query is as follows:

```
$query = "UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code=\"" . $verify . "\"";
```

With the \ char you scape the quotes char. Anyways this can be quite confusing so you can use simple quotes.

```
$query = "UPDATE Users SET account_status=1 WHERE verification_code='$verify'";
```

Note that you can make a reference to a php variable within quotes like above.

**BTW. Your error is that you are using the concatenation characters inside a string. It should be used like my first example. Anyways you need to quote the value of the SQL if it is a string. You don't have to do it if the field is NOT a string.**

If you are worried about SQL-Injection you can use Prepared Statements instead of plain queries. I recommend to you the [PDO Class of PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php). You can give a try to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) too.